# How can I properly call a list of async functions in order?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, q, edge.js

I am attempting to write a "robocopy /mir" like function within Node.js and cannot seem to wrap my head around how to properly execute several async functions in order.

Some background:

- The script is run on Windows, therefore, I needed to find some way to copy files while retaining modification time AND receiving progress notifications.
- To solve this problem, I went ahead & wrote my copy function in .NET (calling it with Edge.js)--this copy function simply calls back to a Node function reporting file copy progress.  This piece works flawlessly.

To have the files copy in order, my first thought was to do something like follows:

```
Object.keys(filesToCopy).forEach(function(key) {
    var deferred = q.defer();
    var payload = {
        sourcePath: key,
        destPath: filesToCopy[key],
        progressCallback: progressCallback
    };

    console.log('Copying %s...', sourcePath);
    // Edge.js called here
    copyFile(payload, deferred.makeNodeResolver());

    deferred.promise.then(function(result) {
        console.log('%s complete.', result);
    }, function(err) {
        console.error('Error: ', err.message);
    });

    promises.push(deferred.promise);
});
```

Unfortunately, this (as expected) begins copying each files as soon as the .NET function is called, therefore, I get progress notifications for all files at once giving me output like:

```
1%
2%
1%
2%
3%
3%
```

It seems like I need a way to queue up the work to be done before firing it off all at once, with each item completing before the next proceeds.  When all items are complete I would need to be notified.  The solution seems simple enough but continues to elude me as every angle I try comes with another issue.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

**EDIT:**  As stated in my comment, the answer Bergi provided was utilizing a function which *did* in fact return a promise whilst my Edge.js function did not.  I was able to resolve my issue first by utilizing an array instead of an object for `filesToCopy`, then doing something like so:

```
  return filesToCopy.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    return prev.then(function() {
      var deferred = q.defer();
      copyFile(curr, function(err, result) {
        deferred.resolve(result);
        console.log('Completed %s', result);
      });
      return deferred.promise;
    })
  }, q());
```

This may not be the best way to do this but it works for my uses.

Comment: What exactly is wrong with copying them all at once? Should be quite faster. You still can get notified when all have completed through `Q.all(promises)`

Comment: I understand that it's faster, but I want to show a single progress bar for overall progress & a single progress bar for each file...I am copying files up to 15 GB in size and would like to not have to have a separate bar for each file.

Comment: OK… have a look at my answer to the duplicate question. Feel free to comment if it doesn't help you

Comment: I'll give it a go that way...thanks Bergi!

Comment: A combination of Bergi & Anonymous0Day's answers got me where I needed to be.  Thanks so much fellas.  Bergi, just wanted to let you know that I wouldn't consider this to be necessarily a duplicate as Edge.js does not return a promise by default, therefore please see my edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like that will do the trick :

```js
var $j = function(val, space) {
  return JSON.stringify(val, null, space || '')
}
var log = function(val) {
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div><pre>' + val + '</div></pre>')
}



var files = '12345'.split('').map(function(v) {
  return {
    name: 'file_' + v + '.js',
    load: function() {
      var cur = this;
      var pro = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

        log('loading : ' + cur.name);
        
        // we simualate the loading stuff
        setTimeout(function() {
          resolve(cur.name);
        }, 1 * 1000);

      }).then( function( val ) {
        
        // once loaded 
        log('loaded : ' + val);
        return val;
      
      });

      return pro;

    }
  };
});


files.reduce(function(t, v) {

  t.promise = t.promise.then(function(){ 
      return v.load();
  });
  
  return t;
}, {
  promise: Promise.resolve(1)
});
```

Comment: Close but no cigar--I do appreciate the assistance, though!  Still getting interleaved progress reporting.  I think I may have to do something with "async.forEachOf" or something similar..

Comment: i missed in your `t.deferred.promise.then` you are not returning ! you must return something ! try it, and tell me, i will update answer !

Comment: Still no go :(, here's an example of the output:  https://i.imgur.com/91Bk6hD.png

Comment: I have modified my answer with a working test !

Comment: Thanks for all your assistance!  Guess people didn't like this question since it go downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Use `async.eachSeries` on arrays, or `async.forEachOfSeries` on objects.

#### Looping an object

```
var async = require('async');
var filesObject = {'file/path/1': {}, 'file/path/2': {}};

async.forEachOfSeries(filesObject, copyFileFromObj, allDone);

function copyFileFromObj(value, key, callback) {
  console.log('Copying file ' + key + '...');
  callback(); // when done
}

function allDone(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  }
  console.log('All done.');
}
```

#### Looping an array

```
var async = require('async');
var filesArray = ['file/path/1', 'file/path/2'];

async.eachSeries(filesArray, copyFile, allDone);

function copyFile(file, callback) {
  console.log('Copying file ' + file + '...');
  callback(); // when done
}

function allDone(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  }
    console.log('All done.');
}
```

Working example here: https://tonicdev.com/edinella/sync-loop-of-async-operations