# How to return accumulated returned Promise values as array to .then() following Array.prototype.reduce()?

Tags: javascript, arrays, promise, jquery-deferred

Given this pattern

```
someArray.reduce(function(p, item) {
  return p.then(function() {
    return someFunction(item);
  });
}, $.Deferred().resolve()).then(function() {
  // all done here
  // access accumulated fulfilled , rejected `Promise` values
}, function err() {

});
```

what approaches are possible to return accumulated values of fulfilled , rejected `Promise` objects to `.then(fulfilled)` as an array following call to `.reduce()` ?

```js
function someFunction(index) {
  console.log("someFunction called, index = " + index);
  var $deferred = $.Deferred();

  window.setTimeout(function() {
    $deferred.resolve();
  }, 2000);

  return $deferred.promise();
}
   
var someArray = [1,2,3,4,5];

someArray.reduce(function(p, item) {
  return p.then(function() {
    return someFunction(item);
  });
}, $.Deferred().resolve()).then(function(data) {
  // all done here
  console.log(data, arguments) // `undefined` , `[]`
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: Can you clarify "*accumulated values of fulfilled , rejected Promise objects*", please? How should the result look exactly, and how do you want rejections to be treated?

Comment: @Bergi A single array or object containing fulfilled `Promise` values at `.then(fulfilled)` , similarly at rejected `.then(rejected)`

Comment: What is "similarly"? Be specific, please.

Comment: maybe you should take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33549935/2037556)

Comment: @Bergi _"What is "similarly"? Be specific, please."_ Results can be either array of results or object having values as results. Both results - fulfilled , rejected - should be same type of data structure.

Comment: @Anonymous0day _"maybe you should take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/33549935/"_ Could `.then()` be chained to `.map()` and return all `cur.name` to `.then(fulfilled)` as an array of fulfilled values from `Promise` objects iterated within `.map()` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are multiple possible strategies depending upon the specifics of what you're trying to do:  Here's one option:

```
someArray.reduce(function(p, item) {
  return p.then(function(array) {
    return someFunction(item).then(function(val) {
        array.push(val);
        return array;
    });
  });
}, $.Deferred().resolve([])).then(function(array) {
  // all done here
  // accumulated results in array
}, function(err) {
  // err is the error from the rejected promise that stopped the chain of execution
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/d4q1aaa0/

---

FYI, the Bluebird Promise library (which is what I generally use) has `.mapSeries()` which is built for this pattern:

```
var someArray = [1,2,3,4];

Promise.mapSeries(someArray, function(item) {
    return someFunction(item);
}).then(function(results) {
    log(results);
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/7fm3wv7j/

Comment: Returning `undefined` for each item in array at http://jsfiddle.net/uusjs3mt/2/ . Is it possible to continue loop if a `Promise` within loop is rejected ?

Comment: @guest271314 - `someFunction()` has to resolve with its value to contribute to the array.  See http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/d4q1aaa0/.

Comment: @guest271314 - I added another option which uses the Bluebird promise library since is has a `.mapSeries()` function which is built for iterating an array serially and asynchronously and returning an array of results.

Comment: @guest271314 - I'm not sure why you would use `.concat()` for adding a single value.   `.concat()` creates a whole new copy of the array each time you call it.  `.push()` just adds a new element into the current array.  Both work obviously, but when you don't need to copy the array, it's better not to.

Comment: Bluebird version return results similar to `Promise.all()` ; if an item in array is rejected , chain does not continue

Comment: Both versions do not continue if item in array is rejected

Comment: @guest271314 - yes, that is true.  That is the default handling of promises (in general).  You can change that behavior to ignore errors if you want fairly easily by just handling the error yourself.  Your question did not describe what you wanted the behavior to be if any single operation had a failure so my answer is coded to stop processing on the first error and return that error (same behavior as `Promise.all()`).

Comment: The Question was hastily and poorly composed , and lacked clarity as to requirement followiing comment exchange at prior Question. Withdrawing "accepted" from Anonymous0day's Answer and awarding your Answer "accepted". This is to maintain consistently between actual Question at OP and solution provided; instead awarding "accepted" to solution provided in response to comment exchanges of attempted clarification of expected result of rejected promises that occurred after original Question was posted.

Answer (score 2):

One solution possible :

```js
var $j = function(val, space) {
  return JSON.stringify(val, null, space || '')
}
var log = function(val) {
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div><pre>' + val + '</div></pre>')
}

var async = function(cur){
  var pro = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

        log('loading : ' + cur.name);
        
        // we simualate the loading
        setTimeout(function() {
          if(cur.name === 'file_3.js'){
            reject(cur.name);
          }
          resolve(cur.name);
        }, 1 * 1000);

      });

      return pro;
}

var files = '12345'.split('').map(function(v) {
  return {
    name: 'file_' + v + '.js', 
  }
});


var listed = files.reduce(function(t,v){

  t.p = t.p.then( function(){
    return async( v )
      .then(function(rep){
      
               t.fulfilled.push(rep);
               log('fulfilled :' + rep); 
               return rep;
      
      } , function(rep){
               
               t.rejected.push(rep);
               log('-----| rejected :' + rep); 
               return rep;
      }
   ).then(function(val){ t.treated.push(val) })
  });
  
  return t;
  
} , {p : Promise.resolve() , treated : [] , fulfilled : [] , rejected : [] } )


listed.p.then( function(){ 
  log( 'listed : ' + $j( listed , '   ' )) 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Next to the approach demonstrated by @jfriend00, where you resolve each promise with an array where you append the current to all previous results, you can also use an array of promises as is known from the parallel execution pattern with `Promise.all` and `.map`.

For this, you have to put all the promises you create within the `reduce` steps in an array. After that, you can call `Promise.all` on this array to await all the results. The advantage of this approach is that your code only needs minimal adjustment, so that you can easily switch back and forth between a version that needs the results and one that does not.
To collect the results of each step in an array, we use a variant of `reduce` that is known as `scan` and does return an array (like `map`) instead of the latest result:

```
Array.prototype.scan = function scanArray(callback, accumulator) {
    "use strict";
    if (this == null) throw new TypeError('Array::scan called on null or undefined');
    if (typeof callback !== 'function') throw new TypeError(callback+' is not a function');

    var arr = Object(this),
        len = arr.length >>> 0,
        res = [];
    for (var k = 0; k < len; k++)
        if (k in arr)
            res[k] = accumulator = callback(accumulator, arr[k], k, arr);
    return res;
};
```

The pattern now looks like

```
Promise.all(someArray.scan(function(p, item) {
    return p.then(function() {
       return someFunction(item);
    });
}, Promise.resolve())).then(…)
```

<sub>(For jQuery, substitute `Promise.resolve` by `$.Deferred().resolve()` and `Promise.all` by `$.when.apply($, …)`)</sub>

Comment: You define `.scan()`, but then your code example does not use it.  I'm confused.  Did you mean to use `.scan()` instead of `.reduce()`?

Comment: @jfriend00: Thanks, yes, of course. A too minimalistic adjustment :-)

Comment: @Bergi Missing `)` to close `Promise.all()` .  `.scan()` appear to return `ReferenceError: t is not defined` ?

Comment: @Bergi Iteration does not continue if rejected `Promise` in array http://jsfiddle.net/nmjosw8b/1/ ? See OP at _"what approaches are possible to return accumulated values of fulfilled , rejected Promise objects to .then()"_

Comment: @guest271314: Yes, failing fast on rejected promises is the default (and works just like the original code in the question or like jfriend's answer). If you want to keep rejections, [you should use `reflect`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31424853/1048572) - just wrap it around `someFunction(item)`.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, was not aware of that post .Used something similar at http://stackoverflow.com/a/33706461/ . Is Question not specific enough at _"what approaches are possible to return accumulated values of fulfilled , rejected Promise objects to `.then()`"_ that requirement is to return all fulfilled ,rejected promise items to `.then(fulfilled)` following iteration ? Not certain why solution posted accumulated "downvote" ?

Comment: @guest271314: Ah, so you think the OP meant that he wants to collect both fulfillment values and rejection values into the same array? I never understood that.

Comment: See OP at _"what approaches are possible to return accumulated values of fulfilled , rejected Promise objects to `.then()`"_ . Updated Question. If too far removed from what appeared to initially be restrained to, please convey.

Comment: @Bergi _"Ah, so you think the OP meant that he wants to collect both fulfillment values and rejection values into the same array? I never understood that."_ Note , array items do not necessarily have to be promises. Any array item can be any value, or no value. Same result should be returned whether item at index 0 is promise and item at index 2 is not promise .

Comment: Either a) both fulfillment values, rejection values in same array at `.then(fulfilled)` , or b) array of fulfilled values returned to `.then(fulfilled)` and `rejection values, if any , being returned to `.then(rejected)` at same call . E.g., `someIterationFunction(someFunction(array)).then(fulfilled, rejected)` where if `console.log()` was at both `fulfilled` , `rejected` , both callbacks would be called in succession , with `fulfilled` called first. At http://stackoverflow.com/a/33706461/ used approach of returning all fulfilled , rejected to `.then(fulfilled)`

Comment: @guest271314: I'm not sure whether you really mean `.then(rejected)`, shouldn't that be `.then(null, onrejected)` (or even `.catch(onrejected)`)? And no, if you have `.then(fulfilled, rejected)` it is completely impossible that both callbacks are going to be called, a promise cannot fulfill and reject at the same time.

Comment: @guest271314: Regarding the array items, that's not what the OP wants. He doesn't even say anything about what the input array contains. It's just `someArray`, and we are going to map over it with `someFunction`, which might return a promise (or a plain value, or throw). It's irrelevant to us what kind of values the input array contains, be it promises or something else.

Comment: @Bergi _"it is completely impossible that both callbacks are going to be called, a promise cannot fulfill and reject at the same time."_ Conceptually, yes, that was portion of Question; if that was possible . Answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/33706461/ not appear to wait for any promises; immediately return array of objects. Requirement of Question is to return both fulfilled, rejected promises . Not ceasing iteration of next item if current promise if rejected. If both `.then(fulfilled,rejected)` cannot be called in succession, return both fulfilled, rejected to `.then(fulfilled)`

Comment: @guest271314: Well the OP clearly wanted to wait during the loop, that's what his `reduce` solution already did. He only didn't know how to accumulate the results in an array, and that's what both me and jfriend answered. And even if he wanted to get rejection values back, the solution should look like the one by Anonymous0day not like yours. But let's wait for the OP to accept an answer, until then let the vote counts speak for themselves.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, agreed. Question was perhaps poorly composed in relation to what expected results of requirement are. "Whether use `.reduce()` or other methods , loop or recursion , top function should behave like `Promise.all()` , without ceasing iteration when rejected promise encountered , bottom function should behave like jQuery `.deferred.always()`" . Would the above sentence better describe a Question ? Or would additional details be needed to avoid confusion at comments ?

Comment: @Bergi _"it is completely impossible that both callbacks are going to be called, a promise cannot fulfill and reject at the same time."_ Appear to be possible using `.catch()` , see http://stackoverflow.com/a/31524969/ , http://jsfiddle.net/eh6q1xkn/

Comment: @guest271314: That's `.catch(…).then(…)` or `.then(…).catch(…)` (with two promises), but not `.then(…, …)`