# How to resolve an array of resolutions from Q.when()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

I'm fairly new to promises and have a problem wrapping my head around the `Q.when()` chain.

I want to execute my promises sequentially.

This is what I've got so far. It's running sequential but it's not resolving my URLs. `parseUrls(urls)` should return an array of all `parseUrl(url)` resolutions.

```
function parseUrl(url) {
    return function () {
        var deferred = Q.defer();

        // setTimeout as async placeholder
        setTimeout(function() {         
            var result = {url: url};
            deferred.resolve(result);
        }

        return deferred.promise;
    }
}

function parseUrls(urls) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    var chain = Q.when();
    urls.forEach(function (url) {
        chain = chain.then(parseUrl(url));
    });
    chain = chain.then(deferred.resolve);

    return deferred.promise;
}

getAllUrls()
    .then(parseUrls)
    .then(parseCards);
```

Comment: You don't need to use deferreds at all.

Comment: @SLaks I've edited my question. When your comment resulted from my example code not using async code, then this is fixed now. My bad.

Comment: Sounds like a duplicate of [How to return accumulated returned Promise values as array to .then() following Array.prototype.reduce()?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33688342/1048572). Is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sequential execution, **chain** your promises with `$q.all`

```
function parseUrls(urls) {

    var chain = $q.when([]);

    for (var i=0; i<urls.length; i++) {
        (function (i, urls) {
            chain = chain.then ( function (result) {
                result.push(parseUrl(urls[i]));
                return $q.all(result);
            });
        })(i, urls);
    };

    return chain;
}
```

Be sure to put `i` and `urls` inside a closure.

Comment: That was quick. Accepted in 3 minutes. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you want to do, but it looks like you just need to simplify your `parseUrls` function a bit and use `Q.all` ([docs](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promiseall)). `Q.all` returns a new promise for the collected results from the array of promises you pass in:

```
function parseUrls(urls) {
    return Q.all(urls.map(function (url) {
        return parseUrl(url);
    }));
}
```

Comment: `map` does not lead to sequential execution